# Access denied for user 'app'@'10.200.100.100' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to connect to mysql db from my application. I am getting a strange problem. I tried searching all the forums but could not find similar issue. I have an user called app and granted privilege to connect from '%' which I understood is to connect from any IP. I am able to connect from my mysql work bench(remote machine). But when I try to connect from my application server to database I am getting below error. The password is correct, the server configuration is correct. My machine is also a remote machine and I am able to connect with out any issues. My application is spring-boot with hibernate.Please help on this. Do I have to grant privilege specially to this IP?

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'app'@'10.200.100.100' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: Most likely explanation its connecting as a different user. I recommend you check for possible other matches. MySQL has a specific order that it looks for a matching user. It may be matching a user before it gets to `'app'@'%'`. I recommend you check for other users **`SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user ORDER BY user, host`**.  Also, are reverse DNS lookups disabled in MySQL? i.e. **`--skip-name-resolve`**

Comment: Did you try to connect via MySQL CLI from the same machine that connection is failing ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot to flush privileges after modifying permissions.

**FLUSH PRIVILEGES**

Comment: I have flushed, even I have tried rebooting the db.

Answer (score -1):

u can try this for give privelege

```
grant all privileges on databasename.* to app@10.200.100.100 identified by 'yourpassword';
```